# using docusign can we create a document with esignature and secure pdf file

Tags: pdf, docusignapi, readonly

I would like to understand whether dousing has the feature to create a pdf document digitally signed with security like non tampering of the document created.

I want to know whether the feature is available or should I use some other library for java based implementation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DocuSign has [Digital Signature](https://www.docusign.com/products/digital-signature) using [SBS (Standards-Based Signature)](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/standards-based-signatures/).
These require that you have a certificate that is used to digitally sign the PDF so it can only be modified under strict conditions. The viewer of the PDF checks the validity of the signature and ensures the user it has not been tampered with.
To do that you may need to engage with a [TSP (Trust Service Provider)](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/tsp-api/) which is a third party that provides this service.

You can get a [developer account](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/account/) with these features for developers if you need to write an integration that utilize these capabilities.